# " Error: An error occurred while starting the application " while hosting in SmarterAsp.net WebApplication Asp.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, hosting, asp.net-core-2.2

I tried to publish my ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application on Windows Server on SmarterAsp.Net hosting service. It runs fine on the local server, but when I try to deploy it to an SmarterAsp.Net hosted web app show the error-

> .NET Core 4.6.28207.03 X86 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.2.7-servicing-10089    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763    |   Need help?

I tried many methods giving on different blogs and forums site but not able to solve this error, like I tried -

- Capturestartuperrors(true) & usesefling("DetailedErrors", "true")
- `<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\OneMits.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="True" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />`

I don't know how to store error in log file and if stored than do i have to publish again and again my application for small changes like making log file creation.

Still no progress. **What can I do?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your application pool to No Managed Code. You can also read this post http://dotnet4europeanhosting.hostforlife.eu/post/European-ASPNET-Core-Hosting-Error-When-Published-ASPNET-Core-See-Below-Tips!.aspx. Hope it helps!